# error: argument -s/--source is required

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-identity

I copied this code from Github, but its not working to me.

Sample Code:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-s", "--source", required=True, help="Path to the source of shapes")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--target", required=True, help="Path to the target image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

and this output

```
usage: detect_leaf.py [-h] -s SOURCE -t TARGET
detect_leaf.py: error: argument -s/--source is required
```

please help me. thanks

Comment: That output cannot come from that code.

Comment: yeah, thats my fault. i wrong to copied this output. anyway, thanks for response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message in your question title is pretty obvious.

```
ap.add_argument("-s", "--source", required=True, help="Path to the source of shapes")
```

You put `required=True` on this parameter. That means it's required. So, if you try to run this script, and don't put a `--source` (or `-s`) argument on the command line, you will get an error.

If you don't want it to be required, don't put `required=True`.

---

The output you show at the end of the question, on the other hand, cannot possibly come from this code. There is no `-src` or `-trg` parameter in your `argparse` spec. Maybe you're running a completely different program? If so, we can't debug that program by seeing the code to this one.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

I think you didn't put the argument -s in the python excute command. 
Assuming the python code is saved into a file called detect_leaf.py
You have to put the argument -s like below

```
python detect_leaf.py -s SOURCE -t TARGET
```

and There are two ways to access arguments value like below

```
import argparse
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
ap.add_argument("-s", "--source", required=True,  help="Path to the source of shapes")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--target", required=True,  help="Path to the target image")

#It's Dictionary
vars_args = vars(ap.parse_args())

print(vars_args['source'])
print(vars_args['target'])

#It's NameSpace object
parsed_args = ap.parse_args()

print(parsed_args.source)
print(parsed_args.target)
```